# Setting data to array adapter resulting empty items in Android

Tags: android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have the an activity and I am having a problem when filling the data to array adapter. My problem is in the "setdata method" of the array adapter.

In the method parseJSONRespone if I use the next code all works well and the data are showing in Listview:

```
    JSONArray entries = new JSONArray(s);
    lvA.clear();
    for (int count = 0; count < entries.length(); count++) {
        JSONObject anEntry = entries.getJSONObject(count);
        lvA.add(new ObjectLogados(anEntry.getString("usuario"),anEntry.getInt("nr_usuario"),
                anEntry.getString("nh_data_hora"), anEntry.getString("aplicacao"),
                anEntry.getString("tipousu"), anEntry.getString("atendendo"), anEntry.getString("atd_com_preferencia"),
                anEntry.getString("atd_sem_preferencia")));
    }
    lvA.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

but if I use the next, the listview items is allways empty. No data are showing in my listview. What is wrong with my setData method?

```
                JSONArray entries = new JSONArray(s);
                tmplista.clear();
                for (int count = 0; count < entries.length(); count++) {
                    JSONObject anEntry = entries.getJSONObject(count);
                   tmplista.add(new ObjectLogados(anEntry.getString("usuario"), anEntry.getInt("nr_usuario"),                            anEntry.getString("nh_data_hora"), anEntry.getString("aplicacao"),
                            anEntry.getString("tipousu"), anEntry.getString("atendendo"), anEntry.getString("atd_com_preferencia"),
                            anEntry.getString("atd_sem_preferencia")));
                }
                lvA.setData(tmplista);
```

Here is my Activity

```
public class LogadosActivity extends Activity {
    ObjectLogados cur_ob;
    ArrayList<ObjectLogados> lista = new ArrayList<ObjectLogados>();
    ArrayList<ObjectLogados> tmplista= new ArrayList<ObjectLogados>();
    ListviewLogAdapter lvA;
    ListView lv;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activty_logados);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_log);
        View v = (View) findViewById(R.id.empty_log);

        lv.setEmptyView(v);

        lvA = new ListviewLogAdapter(LogadosActivity.this, lista);
        lv.setAdapter(lvA);
        lvA.setData(lista);
        //..do more something  
        execute_search();
    }

    private void parseJSONRespone(JSONObject response) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {

        JSONArray LResult = response.getJSONArray("result");
        String s = LResult.get(0).toString();

        JSONArray entries = new JSONArray(s);
        tmplista.clear();
        //lvA.clear();
        for (int count = 0; count < entries.length(); count++) {
            JSONObject anEntry = entries.getJSONObject(count);
            //lvA.add(new ObjectLogados(anEntry.getString("usuario"),anEntry.getInt("nr_usuario"),
                    tmplista.add(new ObjectLogados(anEntry.getString("usuario"), anEntry.getInt("nr_usuario"),
                    anEntry.getString("nh_data_hora"), anEntry.getString("aplicacao"),
                    anEntry.getString("tipousu"), anEntry.getString("atendendo"), anEntry.getString("atd_com_preferencia"),
                    anEntry.getString("atd_sem_preferencia")));
        }
        lvA.setData(tmplista);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

    private void execute_search() {
        String url = Common.getServerURL() + "\"PrefAtdMed\"";
         JsonObjectRequest jr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                parseJSONRespone(response);
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });


        jr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(Common.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS,
                Common.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        Common.getInstance().addToReqQueue(jr, "jreq");     }
}
```

My Model is:

```
public class ObjectLogados {
    private String usuario;

    private int nr_usuario;
    private String nh_data_hora;
    private String aplicacao;
    private String tipousu;
    private String atendendo;
    private String atd_com_preferencia;
    private String atd_sem_preferencia;

    public Boolean getBatd_com_preferencia() {
        return atd_com_preferencia != null && atd_com_preferencia.equals("T");
    }

    public Boolean getBatd_sem_preferencia() {
        return atd_sem_preferencia != null && atd_sem_preferencia.equals("T");
    }

    public Boolean getBatendendo() {
        return atendendo != null && atendendo.equals("T");
    }


    public String getAplicacao() {
        return aplicacao;
    }

    public void setAplicacao(String aplicacao) {
        this.aplicacao = aplicacao;
    }

    public String getAtd_com_preferencia() {
        return atd_com_preferencia;
    }

    public void setAtd_com_preferencia(String  atd_com_preferencia) {
        this.atd_com_preferencia = atd_com_preferencia;
    }

    public String  getAtd_sem_preferencia() {
        return atd_sem_preferencia;
    }

    public void setAtd_sem_preferencia(String  atd_sem_preferencia) {
        this.atd_sem_preferencia = atd_sem_preferencia;
    }

    public String  getAtendendo() {
        return atendendo;
    }

    public void setAtendendo(String  atendendo) {
        this.atendendo = atendendo;
    }

    public String getNh_data_hora() {
        return nh_data_hora;
    }

    public void setNh_data_hora(String nh_data_hora) {
        this.nh_data_hora = nh_data_hora;
    }

    public String getTipousu() {
        return tipousu;
    }

    public void setTipousu(String tipousu) {
        this.tipousu = tipousu;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public int getNr_usuario() {
        return nr_usuario;
    }

    public void setNr_usuario(int nr_usuario) {
        this.nr_usuario = nr_usuario;
    }


    public ObjectLogados( String usuario, int nr_usuario,String nh_data_hora,  String aplicacao, String tipousu, String atendendo, String atd_com_preferencia, String atd_sem_preferencia)
    {
        super();
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.nr_usuario = nr_usuario;
        this.nh_data_hora = nh_data_hora;
        this.aplicacao = aplicacao;
        this.tipousu = tipousu;
        this.atendendo = atendendo;
        this.atd_com_preferencia = atd_com_preferencia;
        this.atd_com_preferencia = atd_sem_preferencia;
    }

}
```

My adapter is:

```
public class ListviewLogAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ObjectLogados> {
    ArrayList<ObjectLogados> items;
    private Activity context;


    public ListviewLogAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<ObjectLogados> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.singlerowlog, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public void add(ObjectLogados items){
        Log.v("AddView", items.getUsuario());
        this.items.add(items);
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<ObjectLogados> items) {
        this.items = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ObjectLogados o = items.get(position);
        final ViewHolder holder;
        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singlerowlog, null);// e' preciso fazer o inflate pois a view nao ainda nao esta em activity alguma
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.ivImgMedLog= (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.ivp_imagemedlog) ;
            holder.tv_usuario = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_hnomemedlogado);
            holder.cb_atendendo=(CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.chk_atendendo);
            holder.cb_atd_com_preferencia=(CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.chk_atendendo_cp);
            holder.cb_atd_sem_preferencia=(CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.chk_atendendo_sp);
            holder.tv_nh_data_hora=(TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_datalog);
            holder.tv_aplicacao=(TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_applog);
            holder.tv_tipousu=(TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_tipousulog);

            vi.setTag(holder);

        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tv_usuario.setText(o.getUsuario());
        holder.tv_nh_data_hora.setText(o.getNh_data_hora());
        holder.tv_aplicacao.setText(o.getAplicacao());
        holder.tv_tipousu.setText(o.getTipousu());

        holder.cb_atendendo.setChecked(o.getBatendendo());
        holder.cb_atd_com_preferencia.setChecked(o.getBatd_com_preferencia());
        holder.cb_atd_sem_preferencia.setChecked(o.getBatd_sem_preferencia());

        String imageKey="MED"+String.valueOf(o.getNr_usuario());
        final Bitmap bitmap = Common.getInstance().getBitmapFromMemCache(imageKey);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            holder.ivImgMedLog.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }else {
            //new ImageDownloaderTask(context, Common.getServerURL() + "\"RetrieveImagePac\"", Integer.valueOf(o.getPront()), holder.ivImg).execute();
            holder.ivImgMedLog.setImageDrawable(context.getResources()
                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.empty));
            downloadimage(holder.ivImgMedLog,o.getNr_usuario());
        }


        return vi;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_usuario;
        TextView tv_nh_data_hora;
        TextView tv_aplicacao;
        TextView tv_tipousu;
        CheckBox cb_atendendo;
        CheckBox cb_atd_com_preferencia;
        CheckBox  cb_atd_sem_preferencia;
        ImageView ivImgMedLog;

    }

    private void downloadimage(final ImageView imageView,final int nr){
        //final ImageView imageView=imV;
        String url=Common.getServerURL() + "\"RetrieveImageStaff\"";
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
        ja.put(nr);

        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonBody.put("_parameters", ja);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonObjectRequest jr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                jsonBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                JSONObject anEntry = null, entries = null;
                String ims = "";
                try {   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    JSONArray LResult = response.getJSONArray("result");
                    String s = LResult.get(0).toString();
                    anEntry = new JSONObject(s);
                    ims = anEntry.getString("imagem");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                Bitmap decodedByte = null;
                try {
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(ims)) {
                        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(ims, Base64.DEFAULT);
                        decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                        if (imageView != null) {
                            if (decodedByte != null) {
                                imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
                                Common.getInstance().addBitmapToMemoryCache("MED"+String.valueOf(nr), decodedByte);
                            } else {
                                imageView.setImageDrawable(imageView.getContext().getResources()
                                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.empty));
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        imageView.setImageDrawable(imageView.getContext().getResources()
                                .getDrawable(R.drawable.empty));
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Log.v(TAG, error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(context, "Erro adquirindo imagem...." + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        jr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(Common.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS,
                Common.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        Common.getInstance().addToReqQueue(jr, "jreq"); //reqQueue.add(jr);
    }

}
```

My layout is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/h_namepac"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Usuários Logados"
        android:background="@color/wallet_holo_blue_light"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/listContainerLogados"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/h_namepac"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView android:id="@+id/list_log"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="#FFCC00"
            android:dividerHeight="4px"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/empty_log"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Sem itens"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to reset items every time ? A usual scneario is where you instead of resetting your items array you add items to it and call notifyDataSetChanged method!

I think in first case when you do lva.add (assuming it is list view object), adapter takes care of adding items to the list for you. However, if you are using setData, I think it is resetting your items array every time, instead of adding data to it.

Solution would be to add items to your arrayList and call notifyDataSetChanged post addition.

Comment: I need refetch the data again to fill the listview when needed. I need clear old data and add new data.  My setData method is:  public void setData(ArrayList<ObjectQueue> items) {
        this.items = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }  and I don´t understand why it is not working. I can see the array is filling with data with logcat but it´s not showing the items in listview.

Comment: you are calling lvA.setData(lista);
 before execute_search(). Until you  get back the response from call back, your listview would be shown as empty. However, inside your parse method setData should anyways refresh the list with filled values